# Cypress: Wait for all requests to /graphql endpoint

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to add a `wait` to **all** requests to `/graphql`. I would like the requests to automatically wait. However, I am getting the following error:

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

I have tried multiple ways to add it (Note I am setting the alias as mentioned [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/working-with-graphql#Alias-multiple-queries-or-mutations)):

```js
Before(() => {
  cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql', handleGraphql);
});

function handleGraphql(req) {
  req.alias = `gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`;

  // The different ways that I have tried:
  setTimeout(() => cy.wait(`@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`), 100);
  new Cypress.Promise(() => cy.wait(`@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`))
}
```

I then have also tried this function:

```js
function handleGraphql(req) {
  req.alias = `gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`;
  cy.wait(`@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`);
}
```

but then I get the following error:

> Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: gql9b93b362-d715-4aae-928b-71b406381350Query. No request ever occurred.

I found that you can add some events to the `req`, but none of them seem to do what I want, as I am getting the `returned a promise` error from above.

```js
function handleGraphql(req) {
  req.alias = `@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`;
  req.continue(() => {
    cy.wait(`@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`);
  });
}
```

Comment: You have to put cy.wait(alias) outside intercept handler. By the time `cy.wait(@gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query)` is invoked, the request has already happened.

Answer (score 2):

***Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command...*** refers to the fact that you are waiting on the intercept alias within the handler.

Since the handler is event response code, the usual pattern is

```js
cy.intercept(...)  // set up the listener

cy.visit(...)  // trigger the events (might also be from UI event like click())

cy.wait('@my-alias')
```

But this means the aliases should be known ahead of time.

Simplest is if you can find out all the ids,

```js
const aliases = ['1', '2', '3'].map(id => `@gql${id}Query`)

const handleGraphql = (req) => req.alias = `gql${req.headers['query-id']}Query`;

before(() => {
  cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql', handleGraphql)  // set up the listener
})

it('waits for all ids', () => {
  cy.visit(...)  // trigger the events (might also be from UI event like click())

  cy.wait(aliases)
}
```

If you can't be specific about the ids, then you either need to wait an arbitrary time for all requests to happen (which is flaky if the wait is too short, or annoying if the wait is too long) or assert an element or other DOM artefact that only appears after all requests are finished.

---

Your id's are generated, so don't use them in the alias. Use a "generic" alias and wait for the required count

```js
const calls = 4

before(() => {
 cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql').as('gqlQuery')
})

it('waits for all ids', () => {
 cy.visit(...)  // trigger the events (might also be from UI event like click())

 cy.wait(`@gqlQuery.${calls}`)
}
```

There's some warnings around the `alias.n` syntax being undocumented, but you could substitute

```js
Cypress._.times(calls, () => cy.wait('@gqlQuery'))
```

Comment: This won't work, as you are manually waiting for the items in the `it` statement. I need it to automatically handle it. Also, the ids are automatically generated (which I didn't mention since I didn't think it was relevant).

Comment: The point is, how does Cypress know when "all" requests have been fired? Do you at least know how many requests there are?

Comment: I have no idea how many requests there are.

Comment: Then see my comment about waiting for some other indicator on the page.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Cypress._.times(calls, () => cy.wait('@gqlQuery'))`. Reasoning: According to cypress the underscore means it comes from lodash and lodash docs shows what I wrote in my comment as the proper call to times. https://lodash.com/docs#times

Comment: Yes, thanks I will correct the syntax.